# How do I compute a discounted price or the regular price after the inputs?

Tags: java

I still am a student and still learning java and I just recently learned how `if...else...` works but I don't know how to properly use it. How do I compute and display the amount of the total price using the `if...else....`

The problem:

A rice store nearby is on sale. All rice is sold at **10% (.1) off per kilo** if the customer buys at least 11 kilos. For anything less than that, the regular price applies.

Here is the list of prices:

Lion - Php48/kilo

Ganador - Php50/kilo

Conchita - Php47/kilo

Other types of rice - Php45/kilo

Let the user **input the rice purchased and the kilos** and **then compute and display the total amount the customer needs to pay**.

**Example:** If a customer buys 3 kilos of Lion rice, your program is expected to only compute 3 kilos with the regular price.

**Note: Customers may buy rice in any quantity, even half a kilo.**

My code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("List of prices: ");
        System.out.println("Lion - Php48/kilo");
        System.out.println("Ganador - Php50/kilo");
        System.out.println("Conchita - Php47/kilo");
        System.out.println("Other types of rice - Php45/kilo");
        System.out.println(" ");
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type of rice: ");
        String rice = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(" ");

        System.out.println("Kilos of rice: ");
        int kilo = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(" ");
        
        System.out.println("Type of rice: " +rice);
        System.out.println("Kilos of rice: " +kilo);
        
        if(kilo>11)
        {
            System.out.println("You have a discount of 10%.");
        }
        else if(kilo<11)
        {
            System.out.println("You have no discount of 10%.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Even though your code is incomplete, I can see these problems with your code: 1. It should be `>= 11` rather than `> 11` since for exactly 11 kilos you get a discount as well. 2. `kilo` should be of type `double` since the customer may pick fractional amounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem statement says that any amount of rice can be bought, even half a kilo. Computers cannot accept vulgar fractions, like ½, but they can accept decimal fractions so the type for variable `kilo` should be `double` (and not `int`).

Think how you would do the calculation. You need to get the price for the type of rice that the user entered. I would use a [switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement or a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) but since you may not have already learned those and since you state that this is an exercise in using `if...else`, the below code uses `if...else` to get the price for the requested type of rice.

After you get the price, you simply multiply by the entered amount. Now you apply the discount. A discount of 10% means that you multiply the price by `0.9`.

Here is the code.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("List of prices: ");
        System.out.println("Lion - Php48/kilo");
        System.out.println("Ganador - Php50/kilo");
        System.out.println("Conchita - Php47/kilo");
        System.out.println("Other types of rice - Php45/kilo");
        System.out.println(" ");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type of rice: ");
        String rice = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(" ");

        System.out.println("Kilos of rice: ");
        double kilo = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(" ");

        System.out.println("Type of rice: " + rice);
        System.out.println("Kilos of rice: " + kilo);
        int price;
        if ("Lion".equals(rice)) {
            price = 48;
        }
        else if ("Ganador".equals(rice)) {
            price = 50;
        }
        else if ("Conchita".equals(rice)) {
            price = 47;
        }
        else {
            price = 45;
        }
        double cost = price * kilo;

        if (kilo >= 11) {
            System.out.println("You have a discount of 10%.");
            cost *= 0.9;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You have no discount of 10%.");
        }
        System.out.println("Cost: " + cost);
    }
}
```

Note that you need to compare strings using method `equals`. Refer to [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Here is output of a sample run of the above code.

```
List of prices: 
Lion - Php48/kilo
Ganador - Php50/kilo
Conchita - Php47/kilo
Other types of rice - Php45/kilo
 
Type of rice: 
Ganador
 
Kilos of rice: 
11.5
 
Type of rice: Ganador
Kilos of rice: 11.5
You have a discount of 10%.
Cost: 517.5
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to this problem is utilizing conditional(e.g:if) statements or a HashMap to determine the value of the type of rice the customer selected.

1. Step 1: determine the type of rice.
2. Step 2: determine the price of the rice from Step 1
3. Step 3: determine whether or not the quantity of rice the customer selected is >=11 kilos
4. Step 4: if Step 3 is true, then apply a 90% discount on the totalPrice

Please also consider that if any other type of rice is provided the default price is 45.

Code Example below: utilizing a HashMap.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        //declaring local variables 
        int priceOfOtherTypesOfRice = 45;
        double discountValue = 0.9;
        HashMap<String,Integer> ricePriceMap  = new HashMap<>();
        ricePriceMap.put("Lion", 48);
        ricePriceMap.put("Ganador", 50);
        ricePriceMap.put("Conchita", 47);
        double totalPrice =0.0;             
        
        System.out.println("List of prices: ");
        System.out.println("Lion - Php48/kilo");
        System.out.println("Ganador - Php50/kilo");
        System.out.println("Conchita - Php47/kilo");
        System.out.println("Other types of rice - Php45/kilo");
        System.out.println(" ");
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type of rice: ");
        String rice = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(" ");

        System.out.println("Kilos of rice: ");
        int kilo = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(" ");
        
        System.out.println("Type of rice: " +rice);
        System.out.println("Kilos of rice: " +kilo);
        if(kilo>11)
        {
            System.out.println("You have a discount of 10%.");
            totalPrice  =kilo * ((discountValue)*ricePriceMap.getOrDefault(rice, priceOfOtherTypesOfRice));
        }
        else if(kilo<11)
        {
            System.out.println("You have no discount of 10%.");
            totalPrice  =kilo * ricePriceMap.getOrDefault(rice, priceOfOtherTypesOfRice);
        }
        System.out.println("Final total cost of rice is " + totalPrice);

    }
}
```

Console output:
[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sfa1.png]